# Replace array response with page response using springdoc-openapi

Tags: springdoc

I have a controller endpoint that returns a list of Strings.
I have code in my conversion layer that replaces this with a Page of Strings. (Page is a class I have written.) How do I tell spring-docs to handle this. By default, springdoc declares the response to be a JSON array of Strings.

I can get it to replace lists that are fields inside my responses like this:

```
SpringDocUtils.getConfig().replaceWithClass(List.class, Page.class);
```

but I don't want it to do that. In fact, the Page has a List field, so that turns into a Page field, which itself has a Page field, and so on.

With springfox, I could configure it like this:

```
docket.alternateTypeRules(AlternateTypeRules.newRule(
    typeResolver.resolve(List.class, typeResolver.resolve(String.class)), 
    typeResolver.resolve(Page.class, typeResolver.resolve(String.class))));
```

That replaces responses of `List<String>` with `Page<String>`. I want to do the same thing, but with spring-doc.

Comment: Did you try customizing the model-resolver?

Comment: @DebarghaRoy I tried implementing ModelConverter, but without any success.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own Bean that implements ModelConverter.
And using the resolve method, you have access to all the response types, that you can change as desired.

You have [sample code](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/blob/master/springdoc-openapi-common/src/main/java/org/springdoc/core/converters/ResponseSupportConverter.java) here.